# Cropping an image via GD and sticking with the top part

Tags: php, image, resize, gd

I have this script and been breaking my head on trying to change it so that instead of cropping the center part of the image it will crop from the top to the $height sent to the function, any help will be extremely great:

```
function img_resizer($src,$quality,$w,$h,$saveas) {
    /* v2.5 with auto crop */
    $r=1;
    $e=strtolower(substr($src,strrpos($src,".")+1,3));
    if (($e == "jpg") || ($e == "peg")) {
        $OldImage=ImageCreateFromJpeg($src) or $r=0;
    } elseif ($e == "gif") {
        $OldImage=ImageCreateFromGif($src) or $r=0;
    } elseif ($e == "bmp") {
        $OldImage=ImageCreateFromwbmp($src) or $r=0;
    } elseif ($e == "png") {
        $OldImage=ImageCreateFromPng($src) or $r=0;
    } else {
        _o("Not a Valid Image! (".$e.") -- ".$src);$r=0;
    }
    if ($r) {
        list($width,$height)=getimagesize($src);
        // check if ratios match
        $_ratio=array($width/$height,$w/$h);
        if ($_ratio[0] != $_ratio[1]) { // crop image

            // find the right scale to use
            $_scale=min((float)($width/$w),(float)($height/$h));

            // coords to crop
            $cropX=(float)($width-($_scale*$w));
            $cropY=(float)($height-($_scale*$h));

            // cropped image size
            $cropW=(float)($width-$cropX);
            $cropH=(float)($height-$cropY);

            $crop=ImageCreateTrueColor($cropW,$cropH);
            // crop the middle part of the image to fit proportions
            ImageCopy(
                $crop,
                $OldImage,
                0,
                0,
                (int)($cropX/2),
                (int)($cropY/2),
                $cropW,
                $cropH
            );
        }

        // do the thumbnail
        $NewThumb=ImageCreateTrueColor($w,$h);
        if (isset($crop)) { // been cropped
            ImageCopyResampled(
                $NewThumb,
                $crop,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                $w,
                $h,
                $cropW,
                $cropH
            );
            ImageDestroy($crop);
        } else { // ratio match, regular resize
            ImageCopyResampled(
                $NewThumb,
                $OldImage,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                $w,
                $h,
                $width,
                $height
            );
        }
        _ckdir($saveas);
        ImageJpeg($NewThumb,$saveas);
        ImageDestroy($NewThumb);
        ImageDestroy($OldImage);
    }
    return $r;
}
img_resizer("profile.jpg","",114,89,"profile_small.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok changing one line solved it:

```
        // crop from top of the image to fit proportions
        ImageCopy(
            $crop,
            $OldImage,
            0,
            0,
            (int)($cropX/2),
```

> ```
>             (int)(0),
> ```

```
            $cropW,
            $cropH
        );
```